# Create tables with data not linked with specific domain class

Tags: database, grails

In my Grails project I need to add some tables in db when application runs for first time.
In DataSource file I've set up the value of dbCreate as "create", so tables linked to domain classes are created. I need also to add some other tables that are not defined in a domain class. For example, I need a table with all world countries.

Is there a way to create the table with data without adding it manually or via import in database (using phpmyadmin)?

Answer (score 1):

Ever consider using the [database migration](http://grails.org/plugin/database-migration) plugin? It's perfectly suited for something like this.

Comment: Do you know how to allow the creation of complete db as my needs with this plugin?